# Java, convert hashMap to array or empty array

Tags: java, arrays

Im a bit beginner. Funny or not, I dont know how to create an empty typed array. My class:

```
class Depot
{
}
```

storing them:

```
private final HashMap<Integer, Depot> depots;
depots = new HashMap<>();
```

and I want to return them:

```
public Depot[] getDepots()
{
    if (depots.values().isEmpty())
    {
        return (Depot[]) new Object[0]; ***
    }
    else
    {
        return depots.values().toArray(new Depot[depots.values().size()-1]);
    }
}
```

as an array. Now when there is no depots, them comes the tricky part. First of all, this line `depots.values().size()-1` fails. The `return (Depot[]) new Object[0]`; seems to be OK, but still triggers an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Depot;`

Comment: why not just `new Depot[0]`?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to cast. Just create a `Depot[]` in the first place :

```
public Depot[] getDepots()
{
    if (depots.isEmpty())
    {
        return new Depot[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return depots.values().toArray(new Depot[depots.size()]);
    }
}
```

Also note that the length of the array in the else clause should be `depots.values().size()` (or `depots.size()`), not `depots.values().size() - 1`. If you pass a too small array to `toArray()`, that array will not be used by that method, and a new array will be created.

Comment: Why not `depots.values().size()`, if OP prefers so? Once you drop minus one, do you even need a conditional?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It would be pointless to pass a too small array to that method, since it will cause `toArray()` to ignore the passed array and create a large enough array. Therefore I assumed it wasn't intentional. And while it's true that `depots.values().toArray(new Depot[depots.size()]);` would also work for the empty case, perhaps it would be a little more efficient not to call `values()` and `toArray()` when the Map is empty (though it probably won't make a noticeable difference).